# Ruby on Rails - Referencing Image in Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using [jquery.infinitescroll.js](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll) in my Rails 5.0 app.  I have the script in my Vendor directory, and I'm trying to customize the JS to use a different image.

I can do it, if I set this property:

```
img: "/img/loading.gif",
```

I tried adding the image in a directory called `img` in the Vendor directory, but that didn't work.

I also tried setting the property to `"/image/loading.gif"` and the image still couldn't be found.  What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to append `.erb` extension to your  `jquery.infinitescroll.js`.

And, in `jquery.infinitescroll.js.erb`, you can use the `asset_path` method:

```
{
   /* ... */
   img: '<%= asset_path('loading.gif') %>'
   /* ... */
}
```

You must move your image to the `app/assets/images` folder.

Or, if you want to use it in a custom folder, add this path to the assets search path with `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "images")` in  `config/application.rb`.

By the way, that's the way recommended by the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets):

> **2.3.3 JavaScript/CoffeeScript and ERB**
>
> If you add an erb extension to a JavaScript asset, making it something
>   such as application.js.erb, you can then use the asset_path helper in
>   your JavaScript code:
>
> `$('#logo').attr({ src: "<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>" });`
>
> This writes the path to the particular asset being referenced.